# Firebase storage security rule file size restriction permission denied

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm trying to upload a blob from my javascript code (EXPO). I keep getting permission error. I'v tried the playground provided by the firebase console but that does not help much as it doesn't reflect what is going on in the code.

> [Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access

Below is a simplified version of my storage security rule

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{filename} {
      allow read, write: if request.resource.size < 99 * 1024 * 1024;
    }
  }
}
```

The file that I am uploading is very small (only 400 bytes) roughly.

I made sure that the security rule structure is correct by simply trying to do
`allow read, write: if true` and that works fine (Upload a 500B text file with no problem).

Im not sure why I am getting permission denied error with such simple security rule extracted from the documentation

Below is the code I use to upload. I'm not sure if the way that I am uploading (using uploadBytes() or blob or XMLHttpRequest) has something to do with this.

```
export async function uploadFileToFirebaseAsync(uri, uid, subfolderPath, fileExtension, filename) {

    // Why are we using XMLHttpRequest? See:
    // https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2402#issuecomment-443726662
    const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function () {
            resolve(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
            console.error(e);
            reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
        };
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    });

    const fileRef = ref(getStorage(), `${filename + fileExtension}`);    
    const result = await uploadBytes(fileRef, blob);

    // We're done with the blob, close and release it
    blob.close();

    return await getDownloadURL(fileRef);
}
```

I thought "maybe" firebase storage was not able to determine the size of the blob, so I also attempted to pass in size as a customMetadata by doing the following. Still doesnt work unfortunatelly.

`await uploadBytes(fileRef, blob, {customMetadata: {size: blob.size}});`

and change the security rule to something like

`allow read, write: if request.resource.metadata.customMetadata.size < 99 * 1024 * 1024;`

Comment: It's unclear from you code that the path of the upload matches that of your rules.  It would be easier if you hard coded the path to clearly match your rules, or at least show the exact value of the path so we can see that they match.  Please edit the question to be clear.

Comment: Will do so thanks. I did verify that the code works fine when I simply change the rule from if request.resource.size < 99 * 1024 * 1024 to if true though

Comment: To make it more clear, I have updated the code to store at the root of the bucket. Same problem still persists. I am able to save when I simply do if true. Permission error when changed to if request.resource.size < 99*1024*1024